# Async Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
async start_game() {
    this.query.getWords(NUMBER_OF_WORDS_IN_ONE_CYCLE, NUMBER_OF_WORDS_IN_ONE_ROUND)
    await sleep(3000)

    // Game loop
    while (true) {
        this.next_play_state()
        await sleep(DURATION_OF_ROUNDS);
        this.wait_for_scores_state()
        await sleep(DURATION_WAIT_FOR_SCORES)
        this.show_scores_state()
        await sleep(DURATION_SHOW_SCORES)
    }
}
```

The above function says that start_game is an unexpected identifier (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RnFo.jpg)

The above code runs on 1 computer with linux, I'm currently trying to run it in cloud9, any ideas?

Comment: `async function start_game()`

Comment: what's your node version ?

Comment: I have tried a few, one was 8.11.3, currently using 10.4.1 (async function start_game() -> unexpected token at start_game())

Comment: Is this a class' method?

Comment: Yes, it's a class method.

Answer (score 3):

Use

`const start_game = async() => { }`

or

`async function start_game() { }`